# Match first line using readline and read the file using seek if the pattern does not exist

Tags: python, readlines

I am new to Python and attempting to read all the contents from a file. If first line contains a certain pattern, i want to read from the {second line, end of file}. If pattern did not exist, i want to read the whole file. Here is the code i have written. The file has 'Logs' in line 1 and some strings in the next lines.

```
with open('1.txt') as f:
    if 'Logs' in f.readline():
        print f.readlines()
    else:
        f.seek(0)
        print f.readlines()
```

The code works fine, i m curious if this is the right way to do or there any improvements to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to seek, just conditionally print if the first line is not "Logs":

```
with open('1.txt') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    if "Logs" not in line:
        print line
    print f.readlines() # read the rest of the lines
```

Here's an alternative pattern that doesn't read entire file into memory (always be hust^H^H^H^Hthinking of scalability):

```
with open('1.txt') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    if "Logs" not in line:
        print line
    for line in f:
        # f is an iterator so this will fetch the next line until EOF
        print line
```

Slightly more "pythonic" by eschewing `readline()` method also handling if the file is empty:

```
with open('1.txt') as f:
    try:
        line = next(f)
        if "Logs" not in line:
            print line
    except StopIteration:
        # if `f` is empty, `next()` will throw StopIteration
        pass # you could also do something else to handle `f` is empty

    for line in f:
        # not executed if `f` is already EOF
        print line
```